# ¿Como se podría identificar una Windows con Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, flask, heroku

Resulta, que estoy trabajando para hacer una tienda y blog con WordPress, entonces necesito ver el estado de pedidos y luego cuando se compre el producto (en este caso mis softwares) pues hay que generar con Python3 una licencia. Así que tengo pensado usar Heroku, un servidor hecho con Flask o Sockets, para que cuando el cliente compre se le envié con Mailchimp el software, con una licencia que solo funcionará en un solo PC. He visto servicios de terceros como cryptolens para implementar licencias, pero quiero hacer mi propio sistema, ya que me sale muchísimo más barato, y se hacerlo. La única duda que tengo es que realmente son dos, me contestan las que puedan. Son la siguientes:

A. ¿La clave de producto de cada Windows es única e irrepetible?, pues actualmente se sacar la clave de producto, y de esta manera se podría identificar cada PC. Ya que necesito que la licencia solo funcione en un solo PC, y para eso necesito alguna Identidad única del PC.

B. ¿Sería buena práctica hacerlo con la clave de producto? Y si no, ¿cual podría ser una forma correcta?.

Nota:
No puede ser por IP, ya que el cliente talvez este usando VPN, tampoco puede ser por MAC si es que el cliente llegará a cambiar la tarjeta de red, o algo así, entonces no es buena práctica a mi parecer.